# Setting Request Cookies in Redirect saved in cURL CookieJar File

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, curl, redirectwithcookies

I'm working on a project where I am using an api to interface with an ecommerce store on a separate site. I am able to add items to a basket through the api, and use cURLS CookieJar to save state. To checkout, I want to simply want to link to the actual checkout process on the main e-commerce site. I need to be able to get the cookies stored in the CookieJar to be sent along with the redirect request however.

I attempted to use cURL to grab the cookie and then follow a redirect, but I misunderstood how it works. Instead of redirecting the browser, it issues a new cURL request based on the 302 redirect.

```
$curlopt = array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => xxx, // this is the path to the cookie file
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => xxx, // this is the path to the cookie file
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mydomain.com/redirect_to_ecommerce_checkout.php'
);

$ch = curl_init(); // run curl
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlopt);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This does seem to send the correct cookies to the ecommerce page, the problem is the browser doesn't redirect, instead it renders out the HTML from the main ecommerce site on my domain.

How can I set the request cookies and actually perform a redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to tell CURL to give you the headers and not to follow the redirect. Then, you can parse for the "Location:" header.  Something like this:

```
$curlopt = array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => xxx, // this is the path to the cookie file
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => xxx, // this is the path to the cookie file
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false, // <--- change to false so curl does not follow redirect
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://mydomain.com/redirect_to_ecommerce_checkout.php',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true // Return transfer string instead of outputting directly
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlopt);
$response = curl_exec($ch); // save response to a variable
curl_close($ch);

// try to find Location header in $response
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);

if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    header("Location: " . trim($matches[1][0]) );
    exit;
}
else {
    echo 'No redirect found';
}
```

Note I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false, CURLOPT_HEADER => true, and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true and then inspected the curl_exec() response that I saved in $response.

You could also try:

```
header("Location: " . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```